# R. ggplot Stacked histogram, Time series, combine two hour plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I have a stacked histogram, it looks like this:
[image: Time of day against count. Stacked by Depth]

I have two issues:

1. I want 24 columns, not 25 - so I need to combine the first and last somehow. st_time is time stripped from a datetime column over 6 months, output is POSIXct 2021-10-11 00:00:00 through 2021-10-11 23:59:54

```
All_M_dives$st_time <- format(as.POSIXct(All_M_dives$begdesc, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), format = "%H:%M:%S")
All_M_dives$st_time <- as.POSIXct(All_M_dives$st_time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

2. I want to order the stack manually by depth 0,25,50,100,200. R does this alphabetically so you can see the incorrect order in the legend / on the graph.

I guess there might be a solution to just use alphabetical dbins and just to rename the legend if that's a possibility, I just thought of that.

```
gg <- ggplot(data = All_M_dives, aes(x = st_time, fill = dbins)) + 
  geom_histogram(colour = "black", position = "stack", binwidth = 3600 ) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M") +
  labs(title = NULL, x = "Time of Day", y = "Dive Count") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45)) 
gg
```

dput can be seen here: [Stacked histogram in R. fill not stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431415/stacked-histogram-in-r-fill-not-stacking)
slight change being dbin is now dbins and the values shown in the figure.

Answered with center = 1800 and factored dbins:
[image: final version]

Comment: "the values shown in the figure": Can you please make the necessary changes and provide the whole ```dput()``` here?

Comment: it's 71,425 objects of 6 variables so no, I can't give you the whole dput or I would have. the other dput does the same thing, just has a smaller dataset and dbins have different labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be solved most simply by adding `center = 1800` to your `geom_histogram` line. This will make it so that each bin is 3600 seconds wide and spans the whole hour centered around second 1800.

```
fake <- data.frame(st_time = as.POSIXct("2021-10-12", tz = "GMT") + runif(1E5, max = 24*60*60),
                   dbins = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 1E5, replace = TRUE, prob = c(20, 2, 1, 5, 5)))

ggplot(data = fake, aes(x = st_time, fill = dbins)) + 
  geom_histogram(colour = "black", position = "stack", binwidth = 3600, center = 1800 ) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M") +
  labs(title = NULL, x = "Time of Day", y = "Dive Count") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45))
```

[image]

You could alternately do the binning yourself and feed that into ggplot to use `geom_col`, for an identical plot:

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
fake %>%
  count(st_time = floor_date(st_time, "hour"), dbins) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = st_time + 1800, y = n, fill = dbins)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "black", position = "stack", width = 3600) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M") +
  labs(title = NULL, x = "Time of Day", y = "Dive Count") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45))
```

To change the series order, I suggest converting the `dbins` variable into an ordered factor. Adding this line changes the sorting and plotting order into the order I supply:

```
fake$dbins = factor(fake$dbins, levels = c("D", "A", "E", "B", "C"))
```

[image]

Comment: center = 1800 works perfectly to bring the data to 24 columns, there's always a simple answer.

Comment: any idea for the legend label issue?

Comment: updated to show how you could use a factor to change the order.

Comment: Thanks very much @Jon Spring, does the job perfectly.